# How to delete line in HTML file with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to using `BeautifulSoup`.

I have a line in an HTML file that is stored locally.

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="report.css" >
```

I wish to remove that line, but I don't know what approach to use to find the line and remove it.

I can find the line using: `old_text = soup.find("link", {"href": "report.css"})`
But I can't work out how to remove and save the file again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to get rid of the tag:

```
soup.find("link", {"href": "report.css"}).decompose()
```

or

```
soup.select_one('link[href^="report."]').decompose()
```

and convert `BeautifulSoup` object back to string and save it:

```
str(soup)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<some tag>some content</some tag>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="report.css" >
<some tag>some content</some tag>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

soup.select_one('link[href^="report."]').decompose()

print(str(soup))
```